# Convert search string to (my)SQL where clause with regex grouping

Tags: php, sql, regex, grouping

I want to develop a simple search for my webpage which uses PHP and a MySQL database and thought it'd be a good idea to use a textfield where the user can enter a basic search term with support for `OR`, `-` and `"`. I don't want to use multiple form inputs but just one textfield for a better user experience just like Google does.

The idea was to write a parser that uses regexes to extract all sub-search groups and then build the SQL statement from these

So valid search terms with its subgroups were

`a b c` -> `['a', 'b', 'c']`

`a b OR c` -> `['a', 'b OR c']`

`a -b` -> `['a', '-b']`

`a "b c"` -> `['a', '"b c"']`

`a b OR c -d` -> `['a', 'b OR c', '-d']`

`a "b c" -d` -> `['a', '"b c"', '-d']`

`a "b c" OR d -e` -> `['a', '"b c" OR d', '-e']`

`a "b c" OR d OR "e f" -g` -> `['a', '"b c" OR d OR "e f"', '-g']`

The result group could then be used to dynamically create the where clause.

I tried myself with regex `([\-a-z])|(\"[a-z\s]+\")` but failed when it comes to the grouping by `OR` which can happens two or more times (see last example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:"[^"]*"|\S+)(?:\s+OR\s+(?:"[^"]*"|\S+))*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HacI5N/2)

**Details**

- `(?:"[^"]*"|\S+)` - a `"..."` substring or 1+ non-whitespaces
- `(?:\s+OR\s+(?:"[^"]*"|\S+))*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `\s+OR\s+` - `OR` substring enclosed with 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?:"[^"]*"|\S+)` - a `"..."` substring or 1+ non-whitespaces

NOTE: If the `"..."` substrings can have escape sequences, you will need to alter that part of the expression depending on the escape char.